# Show Beginning of Content in UITextView (within UITableViewCell)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m83QJ.png)

I have seen most of the answers, pertaining to `scrollRangeToVisible`, `scrollRectToVisible`, others suggesting to trim the text to a number of characters that approximately fills the size of the `UITextView`.

I would like for my uneditable `UITextView` to display the beginning of its content, rather than the end (as is logical for an editable one).

However I am managing my `UITextView` within a `UITableViewCell`, and don't have access to `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear` methods.

I have tried implementing the solutions mentioned above within `awakeFromNib`. That did not work.

How is this achieved?

Comment: I am unable to understand your problem, please clarify what you want to do. Do some good edits...

Comment: Are you trying to display text in UITableViewCell? and do you really need UITextView or Otherwise you can use UILabel?

Comment: @IrfanGul ok I edited the title

Comment: UILabel is not scrollable

Comment: Are you using autolayouts? It seems like an autolayout problem to me...

Comment: @IrfanGul just go reproduce it and you'll see man. This is a very common problem. This has nothing to do with autolayout. If the content of your uitextfield is bigger than the uitextfield, it will not start at the top. It's not rocket science